# Hide sidebar with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I hide the side bar in mobile?

CSS:

```
.sidebar-nav {
    padding: 9px 0;
}

.sidebar-nav .nav-header {
    font-size: 18px;
    color:#FF9900;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">  
            <div class="row">  
                <div class="col-md-3">  
                    <div class="well sidebar-nav"> 
                    <ul class="nav nav-list">   
                        <li class="nav-header">Content Management</li>  
                        <li><a href="../../=">test</a></li>  
                        <li><a href="../../">test2</a></li> 
                    </ul>  
                    </div><!--/.well -->  
                </div><!--/span-->
                <div class="col-md-9"> 
                    <div class="container">   
                        <div class="row">
                            .....
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        <div class="col-md-3 hidden-xs">
```

The "mobile" breakpoint default is 767px. To hide something at that size, just put `.hidden-xs` on it. There is no need to do anything else. If you don't want it to show at the small min width add `.hidden-xs .hidden-sm` OR you can just add `.visible-md .visible-lg`

http://jsbin.com/AmaVUcib/1/edit

Answer (score 3):

Put this in your css, preferably at the bottom. This will hide the sidebar for any screen less than 651px. Adjust the number of pixels to how you want.

```
@media screen (max-width: 650px) {
    .well .sidebar-nav {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Here's a link with more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 4, use add the following classes to hide on xs and sm devices

.d-none .d-sm-none .d-md-block

Read more [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/)